# Laravel's log loggs empty errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm attempting to deploy my Laravel application, however, I'm currently encountering difficulties. The site doesn't work properly, the page name is correctly displayed in the tab and the `alt` text of my loader.gif is displayed, however, nothing at all happens. Attempting to tackle this problem, I found out that Laravel logs empty errors:

-- needed pastebin since SO told me my code wasn't properly formatted (despite the code being perfect as it is) -- https://pastebin.com/S9vBg5aW

just like that. Each time I re-access the webpage the errors are expanded by a certain number of errors. I only recently upgraded from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6.

Comment: Is apache or nginx is producing error logs? If yes, what's in them?

Comment: Strangely, after hitting `npm run production` all the problems are gone? Well... so...

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.6 comes with different channels for logging.

in your `.env`

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

create a file in `config/logging.php`

paste the below given code.

```
<?php

return [



    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),



    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 7,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'critical',
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
    ],

];
```

for More informations

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging

Hope this helps

Comment: This is true, however, I found that out myself before which added nothing to it. I should've added it to what I had tried.